# Why can't I suggest edits on meta?

Tags: discussion, editing, meta

It seems that I don't have an "edit" button for posts on meta. Looking at the meta users page, it seems that edits can be made here if you're a moderator or if you have the requisite rep to make edits.

Is there a reason suggestions are disabled for other users? Not a huge deal, just curious really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some searching on http://meta.stackoverflow.com came up with the following:

- According to [Why can't I suggest edits on SE meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites/97371#97371) it's due to the fact that it would add an another burden to moderators which is explained by the following:

  > Mostly because the per-site metas are generally low traffic -- some of
  >   them count daily visits in the *dozens*.
  >
  > That means the moderators will have to do the work, since the 10k site
  >   users are the only ones that can even see this queue. And on many
  >   sites, like say Bicycles -- there are exactly zero users at this rep
  >   level, even after many months.
  >
  > [...]
  >
  > We were uncomfortable adding Yet Another Queue for Moderators to Look
  >   At across every site in the network.
- According [Per-site metas don't have ability of suggested-edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78223/per-site-metas-dont-have-ability-of-suggested-edits/78319#78319) (which is older than the above answer) it's a feature that is not needed on meta sites.