# This edit would have to be a suggested edit

Tags: bug, editing, review

I was reviewing a question which a new user had just posted on the site, by clicking on the [Review](https://askubuntu.com/review/) link.

[image]

After editing the title (typos) and the main question body, with spelling, layout and English usage, I added a summary of the edits I had made, presumably to help that user format the question better in future posts. However, when I clicked on the <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> button, a message box informs me that the edit I had made **would have to be a suggested edit**.

[image]

I'm happy for any edit I make to be a suggested edit, but there is no option to select this?

http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1758/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-meta goes some way to explaining the reasons behind this, but would't it be better to say that this question is no longer editable?

Comment: Can you explain where you're seeing that? Some of the older users passed the threshold for editing before the suggested edit system came in so won't understand what you're talking about.

Comment: The suggestion has been put in to effect, and the extra info added to the initial question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Do you want to *not* suggest edits?

Comment: @Seth No. OP wants to suggest an edit. They are given a box saying that it needs to be a suggested edit without letting them actually *make* it a suggested edit.

Comment: @Seth sorry, No, as hexafraction said, I tried to suggest an edit, but was unable to save the edits I made. See the edited Post, I have added a Screen Shot of the **Suggested edit** notice I occasionally get.

Comment: Very strange. I would almost say this is a bug..

Comment: So far I have edited around 30 posts today and it has appeared once. Yesterday I edited 80+ posts and it appeared twice. It doesn't make a lot of sense to me as normally it puts the revision in to a queue to await pier moderation, so all the suggested edits I make can be considered as a suggested edit, by default.

Comment: This happened to me too today. When I click save I get the same error message but there was nothing I could do, except abandoning the edit form.

Comment: Is this issue [meta-tag:status-norepro] now? @LuísdeSousa